# I highly suspect this will work

Tags: expressions

When someone says "They highly suspect this will work..", do they think it will work or do they think it will not work?

Comment: The normal interpretation would be that they expect the activity to be successful.  But I highly suspect that this interpretation is sensitive to context.

Comment: Sorry you didn’t bother to post your own ideas and either way, how do you think "They highly suspect this will work" could ever mean anything like “not work”, please?

Comment: Sorry you didn’t bother to post your own ideas and either way, how do you think "They highly suspect this will work…" Could mean anything like “not work”, please? 

One cannot “highly suspect” anything. *Suspicion* is always *strong*; never *high.* Whatever else, that’s because suspicions are not literally laid one on top of another to form a *high* pile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They highly suspect this will work.

While this is open to some interpretation, it would normally be taken to mean that they strongly believe it will work.

---

From Merriam-Webster's definition of the verb [**suspect**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspect#h3):

> [transitive verb]
>
> **3** : to imagine to exist or be true, likely, or probable • I *suspect* he's right.
>
> [intransitive verb]
>
> : to imagine something to be true or likely

In the following examples sentences, **suspect** can be replaced with **believe**:

> I *suspect* [believe] it will rain.
> Call the doctor immediately if you *suspect* [believe] you've been infected.
> The latest research confirms what scientists have long *suspected* [believed].
> I *suspect* [believe] she's not who she says she is.

---

There are other senses of **suspect** that have different meanings and which are used in different contexts.

Merriam-Webster also provides this sense of [**suspect**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspect#h3):

> **1** : to imagine (one) to be guilty or culpable on slight evidence or without proof • *suspect* him of giving false information

This is very *similar* to **believe**, but in a specific legal context.

> The police do not *suspect* [believe it to be] murder in this case.
> The fire chief *suspects* [believes it to be] arson.

---

Finally, Merriam-Webster provides one more sense of [**suspect**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspect#h3):

> **2** : to have doubts of : DISTRUST • suspects her motives

In other words, it's used to express doubt as to the *quality* of someone or something.

---

This "doubt" sense of **suspect** is commonly based on syntactical context.

> I suspect her sincerity.

This means I *doubt* her sincerity.

It's more often meant when it's used with a pronoun and an adjective or noun: *suspect his beliefs*, *suspect her credibility*, *suspect its advisability*, *suspect their motives*.

---

Other syntactical constructions more often have the "believe" sense of **suspect**.

In the question's example sentence, **suspect** is not followed by a pronoun and adjective or noun, so it's more likely to have the "believe" sense.

Comment: Why you deleted all your comments under my answer? and provided a suggestion based on my answer? You completely missed up on the other definition of suspect i.e. doubt. I cleared it for you, and you witty used it.

Comment: @ubihatt Rather than argue endlessly in comments (which comments are not for), the only effective method of expressing what I'd been trying to say was by providing my own answer. In doing so, my own comments were no longer needed.

Answer (score -3):

You have provided a little context, but still it can be answered.

There are couple of other meanings of **suspect**, but in given context following will work fine.

To **suspect** is to ***doubt*** or to ***question*** (something). In your case, it looks more like a doubt, then question.

When you **doubt** something, you are **uncertain** (of something) or **lack conviction** (in something).
*When you question something, you doubt about the truth or validity (of something).*

In your assertion,
`"They highly suspect this will work.."` (sic)

It shows lack of conviction, hence doubt, that it will work. 
But, to say, that it will work or not is entirely depend upon the context and who is saying it.

Cambridge dictionary defines it as:

[suspect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suspect) (verb) (DOUBT)

> to not trust; to doubt:
>
> > I suspect her honesty/loyalty.
> >
> > We suspected his motives in making his offer.

Comment: @JasonBassford ok! changed the answer. thanks once again :)

Comment: Sorry but this still appears to be backwards.   To “suspect” is to believe/conclude based on intuition or reasoning based on circumstantial evidence.    Where’s John?  I don’t know but I saw him go out the door with his gym bag, so I suspect he is at the gym.

Comment: @Jim I prefer to go with dictionary definition. Please provide the source of your claim. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the dictionary definitions you quote (in your earlier edits) support my claim, you just aren’t interpreting them properly.

Comment: @Jim Merriam Webster clearly states that suspect means doubt or a question. Here, in a given case, suspension is based on doubt. And you doubt something or someone if you are uncertain about them or lack conviction in them.

Comment: Ubi, while true, that’s not the sense being used in OP’s sentence.  Try Merriam Webster *to imagine to exist or be true, likely, or probable <I ~ he's right>  vi : to imagine something to be true or likely*

Comment: @JasonBassford you agree to what Jim is saying?

Comment: @Jim there is lack of proper context and we are left to speculate. I used that meaning to which Jason Bassford disagreed and I agree with him. thanks!

Comment: When j read @JasonBassford’s first 3 comments I conclude that he is saying rhe same thing I am saying. “I highly suspect means ***I strongly believe***” ...

Comment: @Jim and I suspect that my explanation is best for the given context. It is not entirely wrong as you put it.

Comment: You just used it correctly!  And in the construction as the OP.

Comment: @Jim that's your opinion. I interpret it as “I highly suspect means I strongly doubt”. Doubt is not always negative. For an example, I can say, "I doubt, my code will work" meaning, I am not sure it will run. My code can run or may not run.

Comment: Well when we’re stuck in the dungeon and our friend says, “I highly suspect the dragon is behind that door.”  Give me a chance to back away a little before you go running through it.

Comment: @Jim I understand what you are trying to say, but let's back to  OP's assertion. I have replaced **suspect** with your suggestion "believe" and my suggestion "doubt". According to you: "They highly **believe** (suspect) this will work.." & My version:  "They highly **doubt** (suspect) this will work.." ….. you got the idea, right?!

Comment: Try doing your substitution on these occurrences: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20highly%20suspect%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Jim that's not what OP is asking, right? we have to stick to question. We both know how a word behaves in a given ecosystem. I rest my case here.

Comment: Well, whatever. I’m sorry I can’t convince you.  Maybe others can

Comment: @Jim I am not stubborn here. I already agree to what you say, but that meaning doesn't fit here. Also, you dodged my question: : "They highly **believe** (suspect) this will work.." & My version: "They highly **doubt** (suspect) this will work..". We have to answer here based on the question asked. I don't know why you are insisting.

Comment: @JasonBassford from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suspect). Doubt does not blatantly translate to belief. That is only the part of it. Here is an example:  "They highly **believe** (suspect) this will work.." & My version: "They highly **doubt** (suspect) this will work..". I request, that we should discus on this question, rather then general set of all possible meanings.

Comment: @JasonBassford You can firmly believe something, or your  belief is doubtful. doubt is more or less "uncertainty".

Comment: I can't see any way the sentence could be interpreted as you suggest. If it said "*They suspect this*" then it would mean they had doubt/questions about whether it would work or not, where it came from, why it was there, or something else. But because it is "*They suspect [that] this will work*" then it clearly means they think it will probably work. No other interpretation is possible (as far as I can see).

Comment: @JamesRandom thanks for your suggestion. Between, if you are reading all my answers and upvoting the one you like, then please refrain from doing so. Your and mine account will be suspended. It looks like favouritism to SE admins.

Comment: @ubihatt I don't know what you are talking about. Do you mean "all my comments"? And surely the point of SE is to upvote good answers? So I voted for Jason's.

Comment: @JamesRandom yes, it is good, but not in a single go. I received 2 upvotes on two different answers after you commented here and on there answer, so I thought you are reading all my answers and upvoting the one which you like.  Anyway, have a nice day!